# GLUE Records inconsistences

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, bind, glue-record

I have configured a DNS server into a vultr VPS in order to be authoritive for my goddady domain example.com

This is the current configuration of my DNS zone:

```
; DNS Servers
@               IN      NS      dns.example.com.
@               IN      NS      d.ns.buddyns.com.
@               IN      NS      e.ns.buddyns.com.
@               IN      NS      f.ns.buddyns.com.

dns             IN      A       108.61.xx.xx (my VPS ip)
```

If I test my domain into http://www.intodns.com/example.com

But I get:

```
 *Looks like the A records (the GLUE) got from the parent zone check are     different than the ones got from your nameservers. You have to make sure your parent server has the same NS records for your zone as you do.I detected some problems as follows:*

For d.ns.buddyns.com the parent reported: ['108.61.XXX.XXX'] and your nameservers reported: ['107.191.99.111']
For e.ns.buddyns.com the parent reported: ['108.61.XXX.XXX'] and your nameservers reported: ['213.183.56.98']
For f.ns.buddyns.com the parent reported: ['108.61.XXX.XXX'] and your nameservers reported: ['103.6.87.125']
For dns.example.com the parent reported: ['108.61.XXX.XXX'] and your nameservers reported: ['108.61.XXX.XXX']
For puck.nether.net the parent reported: ['108.61.XXX.XXX'] and your nameservers reported: ['204.42.254.5']
```

I really don't understand what is happening or if there is any chance to get that test passed.

My domain dns "Glue" record is set into godaddy.com as Hostname like this:
    DNS 108.61.XXX.XXX

And all my nameserver are listed as authorative into goddady namserver list for my domain:

```
DNS.EXAMPLE.COM
D.NS.BUDDYNS.COM
E.NS.BUDDYNS.COM
F.NS.BUDDYNS.COM
PUCK.NETHER.NET
```

I'm really stuck with this

Please, ask for more information if needed

Comment: Please post the real domain name

Comment: Pos duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/613401/ns-list-does-not-match-list-from-parent-zone and http://serverfault.com/questions/478605/mismatch-in-ns-and-glue-records-in-the-parent-zone-where-every-ns-is-still-auth

Comment: I have edited my question, there should be something more, in my opinion all the glue records are set.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to set ns.yourdomain.tld as authoritative, you'll need to set GLUE records to prevent loops and, as a result, unsuccessful resolution. If you are not trying to do so, you should just not set them.

The GLUE(s) record(s) should be the same(s) as the A record(s) for your domain in your authoritative zone.

GLUE records should be set through your registrar

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the concept. What do you mean to set the GLUE through the registrar?

Comment: Your registrar is managing the parent zone for your domain, they should expose some interface to permit you to update this.

Comment: I have edited my question, there should be something more, in my opinion all the glue records are set.